# How to connect Nest.js and NEo4j

Tags: neo4j, graphql, nestjs

I am new to Neo4j and want it to connect with Nest.js,I am using neo4j Version 3.5.12 and 
following the tutorial.I  connect Nest.js and Neo4j by using Graphql but  we cannot get the result and show some  JSON type  and also I try  without using Graphql but the GET and POST were not working.

This my controller

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';

import {Neo4jService} from './neo4j.service';

@Controller('neo4j')
export class Neo4jController {
    constructor (private readonly retriveNodes: Neo4jService){}
@Get()
 async findAll() {
    console.log('retriving nodes as per given query in findAll() method. ');

 //return'Welcome To All';
 return this.retriveNodes.findAll();
 }
}
```

Service

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as v1 from 'neo4j-driver';
@Injectable()
export class Neo4jService {
 constructor(@Inject("Neo4j") private readonly neo4j: v1.Driver) {}
async findAll(): Promise<any> {
 return this.neo4j.session().run('MATCH (n:Movie) RETURN n LIMIT 5');
 }
}
```

Using this I get the result in JSON form.

OUTPUT

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "keys": [
        "n"
      ],
      "length": 1,
      "_fields": [
        {
          "identity": {
            "low": 0,
            "high": 0
          },
          "labels": [
            "Movie"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "title": "The Martix",
            "year": {
              "low": 1999,
              "high": 0
            },
            "id": "82999192-ae57-406e-8c19-d7753d0d5748"
          }
        }
      ],
      "_fieldLookup": {
        "n": 0
      }
    },
    {
      "keys": [
        "n"
      ],
      "length": 1,
      "_fields": [
        {
          "identity": {
            "low": 1,
            "high": 0
          },
          "labels": [
            "Movie"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "title": "A Few Good Men",
            "year": {
              "low": 1992,
              "high": 0
            },
            "id": "c52c721c-c410-45a2-8d2e-824caa51847a"
          }
        }
      ],
      "_fieldLookup": {
        "n": 0
      }
    },
    {
      "keys": [
        "n"
      ],
      "length": 1,
      "_fields": [
        {
          "identity": {
            "low": 2,
            "high": 0
          },
          "labels": [
            "Movie"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "title": "Top Gun",
            "year": {
              "low": 1986,
              "high": 0
            },
            "id": "d121663a-597f-4963-8acc-c68021bee860"
          }
        }
      ],
      "_fieldLookup": {
        "n": 0
      }
    },
    {
      "keys": [
        "n"
      ],
      "length": 1,
      "_fields": [
        {
          "identity": {
            "low": 17,
            "high": 0
          },
          "labels": [
            "Movie"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "title": "The Martix",
            "year": {
              "low": 1999,
              "high": 0
            },
            "id": "453941ca-c309-419b-8cad-41d150e06b2a"
          }
        }
      ],
      "_fieldLookup": {
        "n": 0
      }
    },
    {
      "keys": [
        "n"
      ],
      "length": 1,
      "_fields": [
        {
          "identity": {
            "low": 18,
            "high": 0
          },
          "labels": [
            "Movie"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "title": "A Few Good Men",
            "year": {
              "low": 1992,
              "high": 0
            },
            "id": "79fc529c-bfd1-4f7d-9bae-7f00b6d7d540"
          }
        }
      ],
      "_fieldLookup": {
        "n": 0
      }
    }
  ],
  "summary": {
    "query": {
      "text": "MATCH (n:Movie) RETURN n LIMIT 5",
      "parameters": {

      }
    },
    "queryType": "r",
    "counters": {
      "_stats": {
        "nodesCreated": 0,
        "nodesDeleted": 0,
        "relationshipsCreated": 0,
        "relationshipsDeleted": 0,
        "propertiesSet": 0,
        "labelsAdded": 0,
        "labelsRemoved": 0,
        "indexesAdded": 0,
        "indexesRemoved": 0,
        "constraintsAdded": 0,
        "constraintsRemoved": 0
      },
      "_systemUpdates": 0
    },
    "updateStatistics": {
      "_stats": {
        "nodesCreated": 0,
        "nodesDeleted": 0,
        "relationshipsCreated": 0,
        "relationshipsDeleted": 0,
        "propertiesSet": 0,
        "labelsAdded": 0,
        "labelsRemoved": 0,
        "indexesAdded": 0,
        "indexesRemoved": 0,
        "constraintsAdded": 0,
        "constraintsRemoved": 0
      },
      "_systemUpdates": 0
    },
    "plan": false,
    "profile": false,
    "notifications": [

    ],
    "server": {
      "address": "localhost:7687",
      "version": "Neo4j/3.5.12"
    },
    "resultConsumedAfter": {
      "low": 191,
      "high": 0
    },
    "resultAvailableAfter": {
      "low": 437,
      "high": 0
    },
    "database": {
      "name": null
    }
  }
}
```

I want both .run and .then but in here only .run is showing .No sugection is showing i want **field,properties and id** in above code.